# Extra fields in model

Tags: backbone.js, model, checked

im using Backbone.js to manage models and collections in my app.
So, i have a "Usuario" model that match with a user entity in the database. This is the code:

```
var Usuario = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{
      idusuario: 'undefined',
      apellido: 'undefined',
      nombre: 'undefined',
      dni: 'undefined',
      dom_usuario: 'undefined',
      nombreusuario: 'undefined',
      activo: 'undefined',
      bloqueado: 'undefined',
      recomendar_cambio_clave: 'undefined',
      isChecked: false
   }
});
```

All fields of the model are in the entity user, except "isChecked".The isChecked attribute, will be true when the user model is checcked.
But when i query by "isChecked" js not recognize the variable:

```
console.log(this.model.get('isChecked')); 
undefined
console.log(this.model.get('nombre')); 
Horacio José
```

Any ideas ?.

**UPDATE 1**
It is a extract of my code, where load the collection (of Usuario) via Ajax:

```
var anUrl = $("#ajax-call").val();
var myCol = new CustomCollection({
    model: Usuario,
    filterAttribute: 'apellido'
});

myCol.fetch({async: false, url: anUrl});
myCol.saveOriginal();
console.log(myCol);
```

When, show in console the collection, the models not contains "isChecked" property:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the details you've provided it's hard to know if the error is in your view's initialization or anything else. Using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLLmF/1/) you can see your example works perfectly. I created a view in that fiddle trying to mimic your scenario.

However, don't confuse `'undefined'` or `"undefined"` with `undefined`. `"undefined" == undefined` and `"undefined" === undefined` are both false.

So, your model should be:

```
var Usuario = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults : {
      idusuario : undefined,
      apellido : undefined,
      nombre : undefined,
      dni : undefined,
      dom_usuario : undefined,
      nombreusuario : undefined,
      activo : undefined,
      bloqueado : undefined,
      recomendar_cambio_clave : undefined,
      isChecked : false
   }
});
```

And then:

```
var u = new Usuario();
console.log(u.get("isChecked"));
```

Should give your expected result.

Comment: Thanks for explanation of "undefined" value !. So, the model is loaded by Ajax, and the json returned from the server not have the "isChecked"...is it important ?.

Comment: It's no problem that `isChecked` doesn't come with the info from the server. Values in the `defaults` object are copied to the new object when it's initialized. That means that, by extension, if you have an array in the `defaults` object, new objects will copy the reference to the array (and not create a copy of the array). So be careful not to put arrays or objects in there :D

Answer (score 0):

I solve mi problem. I create dynamically the property "isChecked", querying is the value is defined or not:

```
toggleModel: function(){
    var current = this.model.get('isChecked');
    var status =  current === undefined ? true : !current; 
    this.model.set('isChecked',status);
}
```

Thanks @Meta for the reply.